# Pursuit Curve. Dog Chases Rabbit. Calculus 4.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

(a) In Example 1.21, assume that $a$ is less than $b$ (so that $k$ is less than $1$) and find $y$ as a function of $x$.  How far does the rabbit run before the dog catches him?

(b)  Assume now that $a=b$, and find $y$ as a function of $x$.  How close does the dog come to the rabbit?

Example 1.21

A rabbit begins at the origin and runs up the $y-axis$ with speed $a$ feet per second.  At the same time, a dog runs at speed $b$ from the point $(c,0)$ in pursuit of the rabbit.  What is the path of the dog?

Solution:  At time $t$, measured from the instant both the rabbit and the dog start, the rabbit will be at the point $R=(0,at)$ and the dog at $D=(x,y)$.  We wish to solve for $y$ as a function of $x$.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-at}{x}$$

$$xy'-y=-at$$

$$xy''=-a\frac{dt}{dx}$$

Since the $s$ is a arc length along the path of the dog, it follows that $\frac{ds}{dt}=b$.  Hence,

$$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{dt}{ds}\frac{ds}{dx}=\frac{-1}{b}\sqrt{1+(y')^2}$$

$$xy''=\frac{a}{b}\sqrt{1+(y')^2}$$

For convenience, we set $k=\frac{a}{b}$,   $y'=p$, and $y''=\frac{dp}{dx}$

$$\frac{dp}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}=k\frac{dx}{x}$$

$$\ln\left({p+\sqrt{1+p^2}}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)^k$$

Now, solve for $p$:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=p=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)^k-\left(\frac{c}{x}\right)^k\Bigg)$$

In order to continue the analysis, we need to know something about the relative sizes of $a$ and $b$.  Suppose, for example, that $a \lt$ $b$ (so $k\lt$ $1$), meaning that the dog will certainly catch the rabbit.  Then we can integrate the last equation to obtain:

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg\{\frac{c}{k+1}\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)^{k+1}-\frac{c}{1-k}\left(\frac{c}{x}\right)^{k-1}\Bigg\}+D$$

Again,  this is all I have to go on.  I need to answer questions (a) and (b) stated at the top.

Comment: You can use $\TeX$ on this site by enclosing formulas in dollar signs; single dollar signs for inline formulas and double dollar signs for displayed equations. You can see the source code for any math formatting you see on this site by right-clicking on it and selecting "Show Math As:TeX Commands". [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)'s a basic tutorial and quick reference. There's an "edit" link under the question.

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't sure how to do that.  The link you provided greatly helped me.  I fixed everything the best I could.  Can you or someone else help me now?  Thanks again.

Comment: I could really use a hint or something.

Comment: I don't understand -- (a) and (b) refer to Example 1.18 but talk about variables $a$ and $b$ that don't occur in Example 1.18 -- but they do occur in Example 1.21. Perhaps you could explain more about the context?

Comment: By the way, you can get the appropriate size for a pair of parentheses (or other pairs of delimiters, like brackets, braces, absolute value bars) by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`, respectively.

Comment: I fixed it.  This is evidently a typo in the book.  The correct problem is now stated.

Comment: Now it makes sense. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?  Are you aware of [this FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)? (By the way, the parentheses around the fractions are still the wrong size -- did you see my comment above on how to fix that?)

Answer (score 1):

The book from which this question comes contains a typo.  1.18 is a typo. It should read 1.21. example 1.18 is irrelevant for this problem.

Comment: There, I changed the question.  It makes more sense now, but this is still not enough for me to manage to answer the question.

Comment: This should have been a comment rather than an answer, but you don't have enough reputation for that. [Upvotes your answer]. There, now you do.

Answer (score 1):

According to this paper about pursuit curves:
http://sections.maa.org/okar/papers/2006/lloyd.pdf, it considers $k=\dfrac{b}{a}$, but it does not affect the formulas when $x=0$.

(a) When $k\neq1$, the rabbit runs $y\left(0\right)=D=\dfrac{ck}{k^{2}-1}$ , because $x=0$.

(b) Now that $a=b$, it means $k=1$, then the dog will never catch the rabbit, since their distance's difference tends to $\dfrac{c}{2}$. There is also a special case of $y$ when $k=1$:
\begin{equation*}
y=\dfrac{1}{2}\left[\dfrac{x^{2}-c^{2}}{2c}-c\ln{\dfrac{x}{c}}\right]
\end{equation*}
making $x=0$, $-c\ln{\dfrac{x}{c}}$ tends do $y=+\infty$.