# "Spider Chasing Ant" Graph

Tags: calculus, vectors, graphing-functions, curves

We put a spider and an ant on a graph. The spider is placed at any point along the positive x-axis. The ant is placed at the origin. The spider chases the ant. Both critters move at the same speed.

[image]

I don't know how to find a general equation for the spiders' paths. So far I've thought about using vectors ($<,>$), then equations ($f(x)$), but nothing has worked. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can find your answer in the following post:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199499/pursuit-curve-dog-chases-rabbit-calculus-4